# cannot access request array after ajax forwarding

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

So i'm currently working on a website that loads a container once a button is clicked and the content is loaded via an AJAX function. The problem is at the PHP side, I cannot access the variable i pass through the AJAX function through my REQUEST array. I'm not sure if it is a problem with BIG TREE CMS I'm using.But i really would appreciate some help.

This is the button i use to call the function:

```
    <div class="button-holder">
                <button class="project-btn" data-id='<?=$id?>' onclick="getProject(<?=$id?>)">
                    <h3 class="btn-text">View Project</h3>
                    <h3 class="hide-reveal">&rarr;</h3>
                    <h3 class="button-pike"></h3>
                </button>
```

So this is my ajax function:

```
             function getProject(id)
             {
                 var ajaxUrl='ajax/singleProject?id=' + id;
                 $.ajax(ajaxUrl, {
                     async: true, complete: getProjectComplete
                 });
             }

             function getProjectComplete(xhr, status) {
             if (status == false)
                 {
                     return;
                 }
                 var obj = $.parseJSON(xhr.responseText);
                 $('.pro-heading').html(obj.company);
                 $('.pro-subtext').html(obj.project_heading + '(' + obj.start_date + ')');
                 $('.pro-image').attr('src', obj.project_image);
                 $('.pro-brief').html(obj.project_brief);
                 $('.pro-details').html(obj.project_details);

             }
```

and this is my PHP function:

```
             <?php
             if (isset($_REQUEST['id']))
                 $id = $_REQUEST['id'];
             $obj = new Projects();
             $single = $obj->get($id);
             echo json_encode($single);
             ?>
```

Comment: Please try $_GET['id'];

Comment: I have but it's still not working

Comment: View the source of your HTML and make sure the id is set in the `onclick()` call. At the beginning of your PHP add `print_r($_REQUEST);` to make sure the request array is being populated. Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?

Comment: The Id is being passed to the js function and there seems to be no error reported. I've been looking at the browser's developer tools to track the requests and responses and everything seems to be going well.The URL is sent with the 'id' parameter carrying a value.Only that it's as if the 'id' value never gets to the server php file.when I print out the array... it's empty

Comment: I believe it is not being added to the request array and to which I'm not sure why

Comment: I've fixed it.Apparenlty it had to do with the permissions on the file.I used Netbeans to create the file and I guess it added some restrictions to the file.Thanks for the help